# I have lost my blockchain.info wallet identifier and used a fake email, does anybody know if its recoverable still?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info

I have the password and mnemonic phase, thanks so much for any help

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: This is a support question for a specific service, [try talking to them about it](https://blockchain.info/support-desk).

Comment: Yes, it can be done. I've done it myself, but it's imperative whatever machine you used to create the account or last logged in with, is immediately turned off. Before I go through it, can you clarify your OS, platform, login method (Chrome Extension? Direct login?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can as long as you have the mnemonic phrase.

Enter it here for recovery:  https://blockchain.info/wallet/forgot-password

If you don't have the access to the email address then you will need to contact support at: https://blockchain.info/support-desk

**Here's the info straight from Blockchain.info**

A mnemonic is the passphrase seed of your Blockchain Wallet provided to you when you sign up for a new wallet. The purpose of this is in case you need to recover your wallet at a later date, if you lose your login information. When you recover your wallet with your mnemonic, your password and identifier will be displayed to you. Your main password can not be changed once it is set, therefore your mnemonic will always remain the same for each wallet. - See more at: http://blog.blockchain.com/2015/03/17/whats-the-difference-a-comparison-between-key-blockchain-wallet-terms-and-features/#sthash.kRhvW9CM.dpuf